# excel new row doesn't add under a table

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I have macro file (xlsm) that in vba put certain data under an existing table. then, another table in VLOOKUP searching that new data. in one computer everything work just fine, and the data is added in the new table as a new row, but in other computer the data just placed under the table without being added as a new row. therefor my VLOOKUP function can't find the new data and causing NA#.

I just want that in the same computers the new data will be added as new row under the table. in one it works and in the other not.

what I have tried:

- the proofing setting of the excel in both computers are enabling "adding new rows".
- clearing all rows under the table.
- erase all rows under the table

I think it must be something with the excel setting (other then the proofing).

I will love your help.

Comment: It sounds like you should be specifically adding the new row using the `Listrows.add` method of the relevant `ListObject`. Then user settings aren't important.

Comment: How are you adding the new row currently (the VBA code specifically)?

Comment: Sounds like @Rory hit the nail on the head, but would be much easier to figure out if you share the code.  You can edit your question using the Edit button just below the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all for your help!

in the end it was in the proofing setting - "add new row" option was disable. sorry for the trouble.

apparently when my client disabled this option in another workbook it affected all workbooks of excel. therefor I need to change in my vba code that when he runs the macro it enables this setting. that will solved it.

thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself. There could be a few reasons why the macro is not adding the data as a new row under the table on one computer but works fine on the other.
I would try some of the following

1. Check the version of excel on each computer (is it local or online can also make a difference)
2. Check the table formatting on the 2 computers.

- Table options: Check the table options by selecting "Table Tools" > "Design" > "Table Options". Make sure that the "Header Row" and "Total Row" options are selected. If these options are not selected, the macro may not recognize the table headers and the VLOOKUP function may not include the new data in its search.

3. check if there is any add-in's or other programs that could interfere with your macro